# iOS Youtube API List Video

Tags: ios, api, youtube

everyone, I'm working with the APIs of youtube, I have already created the user and the associated key.

What I wanted to know was:

- How do I get a list of videos created by a user?
- The list of videos for a channel?

Should I take the list and then ask for the information of each video?

I should display them in a table.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of user videos:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?alt=json&author=FUnterasinger
```

`FUnterasinger` is the user

To get the list of video in a channel:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCqAEtEr0A0Eo2IVcuWBfB9g/uploads
```

or with api-key

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId=UCqAEtEr0A0Eo2IVcuWBfB9g&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
```

`UCqAEtEr0A0Eo2IVcuWBfB9g` is the channel id.